# Change the width in panelcustomizable component

Tags: oracle-adf

How to change the width in panelcustomizable component in ADF?

By default the width is rendered to 50% (please see the screenshot) I want facetA (**Left TD**) to be 70% and facetB (**Right TD**) to be 30%.

How do I achieve it?

```
<pe:layoutCustomizable id="layoutCustomizable2" type="twoColumnBottom"
                       showIcon="false" showLayoutChanger="false" inlineStyle="border:5px solid red;">
  <cust:panelCustomizable id="panelCustomizable5"  inlineStyle="border:4px solid blue;">
    <af:outputLabel value="Top Row" id="ol1"/>
  </cust:panelCustomizable>
  <f:facet name="contentA">
    <cust:panelCustomizable id="panelCustomizable6" inlineStyle="border:4px solid green;">
      <af:outputText value="Left TD" id="ot20"/>
    </cust:panelCustomizable>
  </f:facet>
  <f:facet name="contentB">
    <cust:panelCustomizable id="panelCustomizable7" inlineStyle="border:4px solid cyan;">
      <af:outputLabel value="Right TD" id="ol2"/>
    </cust:panelCustomizable>
  </f:facet>
</pe:layoutCustomizable>
```

[image: This is how it renders in browser]

Answer (score 0):

How about surrounding the custimzable areas inside a af:panelGridLayout with two grid cells set to the sizes you need?
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26098_01/apirefs.1112/e17491/tagdoc/af_panelGridLayout.html